# How to get self-updated text reference to files in Mac OS?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to reference a file through text in Mac OS, which will self-update when the file is moved to other folders?

I want to keep a list of references to files that will access those files even if the file is moved. Like it's possible in Google Drive, but in the local file structure instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, symbolic links can't quite solve this, as moving the original will break the target.

Finder's "aliases" (not to be confused with Bash aliases) can solve this, but not easily.  There are ways to create the alias thru the Terminal (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51709/can-i-create-a-desktop-shortcut-alias-to-a-folder-from-the-terminal) and ways to read the current "target" of the alias (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180762/how-to-go-to-alias-from-terminal), but it won't be easy to do what you want...